# How to delete the previous buffer when loading new result from quick-fix window?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript

In the quick-fix window, if I'm loading new results, the previous buffers stay which I don't want. I want only those buffers to stay which I open intentionally (e.g. to write new code, do diff of files or write test cases).

In the case of searching in files, the intention is to temporary open files to see the matching results rather than to keep them. If I keep them open then there will be a large number of open buffers which will make it difficult to switch between them.

To prevent this I added a mapping in my `.vimrc` file like so:

```
nnoremap <expr> <F2> (getreg('#')==getreg('%')) ? '<CR><C-W>p':'<CR>:bd#<CR><C-W>p'
```

This actually deletes the last buffer but sometimes gives an error that `E516: No buffers were deleted`. This happens because the condition `(getreg('#')==getreg('%'))` always returns false.

What is the best way of re-writing this mapping to avoid the error?

I'm open to any suggestions if my way of using Vim is not great

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you clarify what you’re trying to accomplish? It’s usually fine for previous buffers to stay around, especially with the `hidden` option set and judicious window use.

Comment: I want only those buffers to stay which i open intentionally(e.g. to write new code, do diff of files or write test cases). In case of searching in files, the intention is to temporary open files to see the matching results rather than keep them. If i keep them open then there will be a number of open buffers which which will make it difficult to switch buffers. I'm open to any suggestions if my way of using Vim is not great

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar I think you should edit your initial post to provide the details you give in this comment. If I understand correctly, you would like to get rid of every buffer that is not in the quickfix when you open that quickfix? Also, welcome!

Comment: @HarisMuzaffar perhaps you’re falling into a trap of inefficient buffer navigation; I can suggest some other navigation techniques, though they’re tangential to your question. Happy to [chat] about those on the side. In the meantime, Biggybi is right: would you [edit] as much detail as you can into the question, and hopefully someone will be able to work out an answer

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this? At the very least I have a short answer which will supress the error message. If you're still looking I might have something better overall. But minimally you can eliminate the `E516.....`.

Comment: Next level of complexity would be a command and/or mapping that closes all the quick fix buffers at once. Could also be run automatically each time subsequent quickfix commands are run.  I can envision some more sophisticated solutions, too,  but would need to get some additional details from you.